# GWT - login form - browser always asks to remember password event if user/password is incorrect

Tags: javascript, java, gwt

I have a simple GWT login form and a java servlet used for a simple user login. I am using form submit completion event to handle the response, without redirecting to the action target URL, and I want to handle the answer (password incorrect or all OK or any other custom behavior) on the client side and then take appropriate action. If login is OK, then the browser should ask to remember username and password.

The issue is that for every response, regardless if the username + password combination is correct, the browser always asks to remember them.
Any advice? I don't want to load another page because I want to keep the same GWT state. I also tried sending response codes 400 or 401 but it doesn't work (tested in Chrome).

See code below:

GWT onModuleLoad():

```
        final FormPanel formPanel = new FormPanel();
        formPanel.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_URLENCODED);
        formPanel.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);

        VerticalPanel verticalPanel = new VerticalPanel();
        verticalPanel.add(new Label("Username"));
        TextBox userid = new TextBox();
        userid.setName("username");
        verticalPanel.add(userid);

        verticalPanel.add(new Label("Password"));
        PasswordTextBox passwd = new PasswordTextBox();
        passwd.setName("password");
        verticalPanel.add(passwd);

        verticalPanel.add(new Button("Submit", new ClickHandler() {

            @Override
                public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            formPanel.submit();
            }
        }));

        formPanel.add(verticalPanel);

        formPanel.setAction("/login"); 

        formPanel.addSubmitHandler(new FormPanel.SubmitHandler() {
            public void onSubmit(SubmitEvent event) {
            }
        });
        formPanel.addSubmitCompleteHandler(new FormPanel.SubmitCompleteHandler() {
            public void onSubmitComplete(SubmitCompleteEvent event) {
                GWT.log(event.getResults());
            }
        });

        RootPanel.get().add(formPanel);
```

Java Servlet test:

```
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String username = req.getParameter("username");
        String password = req.getParameter("password");
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");

        System.out.println("Login request for " + username + " / " + password);
        if (username.equals("test1234")) {
            // send test response to output
            printMessageToOutputStream(resp, "OK", true, true);
        }
        else {
            resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN); // not working for 400,401,403
            printMessageToOutputStream(resp, "NOK", false , true);
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:**
I tried also status 403 (Forbidden) and it is not working (I updated the code snippet)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you always return a 200 http code, causing the browser to think that everything is OK even when the password is wrong.

I fixed your snippet:

```
   @Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String username = req.getParameter("username");
    String password = req.getParameter("password");
    resp.setContentType("text/plain");

    System.out.println("Login request for " + username + " / " + password);
    if (username.equals("test1234")) {
        // send test response to output
        printMessageToOutputStream(resp, "OK", true, true);
    }
    else {
        // Hey browser, authentication failed
        resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
        printMessageToOutputStream(resp, "NOK", false , true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working either. (tested on Chrome - and also with codes 400, 401)

Comment: This is a non-solution, but why instead of using a form submit you don't leverage the awesome gwt client-server mechanism? Would make your life easier and solve the issue. Guide: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html

Comment: I tried that also, but browser behaves very strangely when using AJAX. For example, using RPC, the Remember password popup is not triggered unless you forcibly submit the form. Also, it does not work on Chrome, IOs (ex. iPhone), and when you type the first part of a username to view suggestions and select it (or hit Enter in desktop), the browser asks to remember the password for half of the username (even though you have previously chosen to remember that full username). So I couldn't make that work 100% correctly

Comment: I think the most important thing is having a simple, secure login. Seems like the "saving password" thing is more of an annoyance rather than a feature a this point. I would recommend to use GWT-RPC and skip it all together (especially since you are putting lot of effort into making it work in chrome but you are not sure it will work as well in the other browsers).